# I want to send a variable from a Controller to a Trait on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a controller that store the data. This use a form Request and after Show the messages on a trait. I am using the same trait on 3 API but i want to know if is posible send/add to the json/array a Custom Message for each API. For example if Category created (Category created successfull o Product Created Successfull) according the api.
 This is my Store on my controller

```
    public function store(StoreCategory $request)
{
    $data = request()->all();
    $newCategory = Category::create($data);    
    return $this->respondCreated(new CategoryResource($newCategory)); 
}
```

I am using CategoryResource like Resource
And this is my trait

```
    public function respondCreated($data)
{
    return $this->setStatusCode(IlluminateResponse::HTTP_CREATED)->respond($data
    ->response()      
    );
}
    public function respond($data, $headers = [])
{
    $response = $data;
    return $response->setStatusCode($this->statusCode);        
}
```

CategoryResource code:

```
public function toArray($request) {
    return [ 'id' => $this->id,
             'name' => $this->name,
             'parent_id' => $this->parent_id,
             'created_at' => $this->created_at,
             'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
            ];
}
```

Is Possible add a custom message per Api Request? May be can i pass a Variable from my controller and  after add the custom message  add the variable to the array?

Best Regards
Sorry my english is not good

Comment: please share your CategoryResource code, and can I ask the purpose of creating a respondCreated other than sending a response? do you have other uses for that?

Comment: I receive the response code for each API and i can put a message but generic and i want to try a custom message per API  ->

Comment: public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'parent_id' => $this->parent_id,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }

Comment: The second comment is my CategoryResource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding attribute to the model directly : [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

> Occasionally, when casting models to an array or JSON, you may wish to add attributes that do not have a corresponding column in your database. To do so, first define an accessor for the value:

```
public function getHasMessageAttribute()
{
    return "the message that you want to pass";
}
```

> After creating the accessor, add the attribute name to the appends property on the model. Note that attribute names are typically referenced in "snake case", even though the accessor is defined using "camel case":

```
{
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['has_message'];
}
```

There are many ways to go from here but;

and finally pass the message through CategoryResource

```
'message'=> $this->has_message,
```

if you want to separate that from the DB entries you can always use [with](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data).

Comment: Work but doesn't difference between store or update. But i have an idea with your example. Thank you so much

Comment: always glad to be a help .. if you want you can change the getHasMessageAttribute to `{ ($this->exists) ? return 'Welcome back' 
 : return 'Horraaaay'}`